Unexpected result when printing bone axes
I toggled on Axes for bones to see the local (I believe, correct me if im wrong) axes for each one
I would now like to print the axes of each bone using a simple script, however this is not giving me the results i expected
Script:
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix

bone_2_name = "Bone 2"
bone_11_name = "Bone 11"

def print_bone_axes(bone_name):
    obj = bpy.context.object
    bone = obj.pose.bones[bone_name]
    bone_matrix = bone.matrix
    x_axis = bone_matrix.col[0].xyz
    y_axis = bone_matrix.col[1].xyz
    z_axis = bone_matrix.col[2].xyz
    x_axis_formatted = tuple(round(coord, 2) for coord in x_axis)
    y_axis_formatted = tuple(round(coord, 2) for coord in y_axis)
    z_axis_formatted = tuple(round(coord, 2) for coord in z_axis)
    print(f"\nAxes for {bone_name}:")
    print(f"  X Axis: {x_axis_formatted}")
    print(f"  Y Axis: {y_axis_formatted}")
    print(f"  Z Axis: {z_axis_formatted}")

print_bone_axes("Bone 2")
print_bone_axes("Bone 11")

I am looking at the torso and shoulder bone (Bone 2 and Bone 11) and visually i can clearly see that it is:
X right for both
Bone 2: Y up, Z forward
Bone 11: Y down, Z backward
But running this script i get:
Axes for Bone 2:
  X Axis: (1.0, -0.0, 0.0)
  Y Axis: (0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
  Z Axis: (-0.0, -1.0, 0.0)

Axes for Bone 11:
  X Axis: (0.96, 0.19, -0.18)
  Y Axis: (-0.19, -0.0, -0.98)
  Z Axis: (-0.18, 0.98, 0.04)

Which shows that for bone 2 y is pointing forward/backward instead and z is pointing up/down
and that bone 11 y is pointing forward/backward and z is up/down which doesn't align with what i see visually
Image with axes showing and Bone 2 & 11 highlighted:



Turns out i was just computing them incorrectly, this script produces the expected results, it prints the local axes of the specified bones in world space without scaling (I did this because i had applied a scale to my mesh object)
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

bone_names = ["Bone 2", "Bone 11"]

def print_bone_axes():
    print("Printing bone axes...")
    armature = bpy.context.active_object
    if armature is None or armature.type != 'ARMATURE':
        print("No armature selected.")
        return

    bones = armature.pose.bones

    for bone_name in bone_names:
        bone = bones.get(bone_name)
        if bone is not None:
            armature_rotation = armature.matrix_world.to_3x3().normalized()
            bone_rotation = bone.matrix.to_3x3().normalized()
            bone_orientation = armature_rotation @ bone_rotation
            bone_world_matrix = armature.matrix_world @ bone.matrix
            
            axes = {
                'X': Vector((1, 0, 0)),
                'Y': Vector((0, 1, 0)),
                'Z': Vector((0, 0, 1))
            }

            print(f"Axes for bone '{bone_name}':")
            for axis_label, axis_vector in axes.items():
                # Transform the local axis to world space
                axis_world = bone_orientation @ axis_vector
                axis_world.normalize()
                print(f"  {axis_label}-axis:")
                print(f"    World Direction: {axis_world}")
        else:
            print(f"Bone '{bone_name}' not found in the armature.")

print_bone_axes()

